# Programming with connected hardware

Tags: python, class, exception, hardware, hardware-interface

I think this will be most easily demonstrated with an example, but the question is a general one.  Say I am using a library like PyVISA, which interfaces GPIB devices with my program.  I have set up a python class for each instrument, so for a power supply, I might have something like this:

```
import visa

class PowerSupply:
    def __init__(self):
        rm = visa.ResourceManager()
        self.ps = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::12::INSTR')
    def getVoltage(self):
        return self.ps.ask('VOLT?')
    def setVoltage(self,v):
        self.ps.write('VOLT '+str(v))
    ...

ps = PowerSupply()
ps.setVoltage(10)
```

Unfortunately, there is the chance that the `rm.open_resource` function may not work, or might return `None` if a device does not exist at that address (in my code I actually wrote a function that did this instead).  My question is: what is the best practice for coding a class like `PowerSupply`?  One could write exceptions into every method that test if `self.ps` exists/is not `None`, but it seems there must be a better way.  Is there?!

Comment: Surely `__init__` should fail in that case, throwing an error?

Comment: to further jon's comment ... it should be the caller's job to manage the dependency
`try:ps=PowerSupply(); except: do_something_else()` ... and init should certainly raise an error about no powersupply found

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The question says that `open_resource` "might return `None`". So no, `__init__` wouldn't fail in that case. But the fix is to _make_ it fail in that case. Add a `if not self.ps: raise SomeException('failed to open resource')` or the like.

Comment: You could decouple `PowerSupply` from your resource even more by injecting it into the `__init__()` method instead of constructing it in there. This way you can switch the implementation as long as the interface is compatible.

Answer (score 2):

> One could write exceptions into every method that test if `self.ps` exists/is not `None`, but it seems there must be a better way. Is there?!

Yes. The way you've written your code, if `self.ps` is ever `None`, it's going to be `None` from the start, and never change again. So, instead of testing it in every method, just test it once:

```
def __init__(self):
    rm = visa.ResourceManager()
    self.ps = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::12::INSTR')
    if self.ps is None:
        raise PowerSupplyException('Unable to open resource GPIB0::12::INSTR')
```

Now, any code that *constructs* a `PowerSupply` has to either handle that exception or be prepared to propagate it, but your question implies that `open_resource` might raise an exception anyway, so that can't be a problem. Besides, that seems like about the right place to handle it—at the top level of your program, wherever you're creating a `PowerSupply` in response to some GUI or CLI or network command, that's where you're prepared to handle being unable to create it, right?

And any code that uses an already-constructed `PowerSupply` doesn't have anything to worry about. You know `self.ps is not None` or you couldn't have gotten the object back from the constructor.